# Jersey + Gson not deserializing java.util.Date

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, gson

I'm having a strange issue with a little servlet which uses Jersey and Gson for the JSON serialization/deserialization. I actually copy-pasted the basic Gson provider written for Jersey, like this one: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/11/02/integrating-gson-into-a-jax-rs-based-application/ and everything seemed to work fine, until I tried to deserialize a Date (in the standard ISO 8601 format), which always gets mapped into my POJO as null.

My first try was to register a deserializer type adapter before returning the gsonBuilder instance, like that:

```
import java.util.Date;

...

gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class,
    new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
                                JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
            try {
                System.out.println(json);
                return (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX")).parse(json.getAsString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
```

This didn't work, and nothing is printed out when I send the POST request. I tried to use the `setDateFormat` method on the gsonBuilder instance before returning it, but this didn't change anything.

I thought there were some others classes implementing the `MessageBodyWriter` and `MessageBodyReader` overriding my own implementation, so I tried to delete my own implementation and Jersey complained that it wasn't able to deserialize the JSON (so there are no other providers, i guess).

I tried to set breakpoints in the `readFrom` method in my `MessageBodyReader` but the request is actually deserialized without suspending the execution.

I should mention that my class contains different fields too, some strings and one date: the string are always deserialized correctly.

I tried sending different dates, starting with `2016-06-23T00:00:00.000+0200` (which should be formatted with the date format string I used in the code above), and getting to the simple `2016-06-17` by removing one part at the time, and it never worked.

I cleaned my maven project, recompiled it and it didn't work.

I thought it could have been Jetty not loading the correct classes, so i deployed the same code into a Tomcat 8 server, and the result was the same.

My last try was to write another parallel `MessageBodyReader` but instead of making it generic for the `Object` type, I made a specific `java.util.Date` deserializer, and still the `readFrom` method seems not to be called.

I seriously don't know what I could try now, do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is here...

```
 try {
     System.out.println(json);
     return (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX")).parse(json.getAsString());
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     return null;
 }
```

to be more specific here:

**"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX"**

java Date and SimpleParser can hold at the most only 3 places for the milliseconds, and there is no wildcard .SSS**XX** in the string used for the SimpleDateFormat, so your parser is throwing an Exception, that you are catching but returning a Date referenced to null, 
Ergo:

Gson is handling a null referenced object,

Comment: This is still not working, I tried to remove the `XX` at the end or adding a breakpoint in the catcher of the exception and nothing happens